# jQuery load() doesnt work on IE?

Tags: jquery

This is my code

```
function grabLatestWho() {
    jQuery("#items").load(window.location.href +" #items");
}
```

Seems not to be working on IE :(

#### update

The function is pretty selft explainatory. It loads the div#items from that ajax page into the div#items on the current page which works fine on other browsers.

It is null on IE.

Comment: *Seems not to be working on IE* is not the kind of problem description a software developer should give. Start by explaining what you are trying to do, what is the expected result, what is the actual result and how they differ.

Comment: Not much info in there.. What does not work ? Did the ajax request return anything ?

Comment: And give possible error messages.

Comment: IE is pickier than other browsers (like FF/Chrome). If it's working there but not in IE then ensure your code is correct. Try running it through something like http://jslint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra space on " #items", maybe?

Comment: I played, I loose :-) . Attach a loadback function on the load() and make some debug - alert - in it. Try to get more infos and feed us with it (did the requests occurs, what is the response content, etc)

Answer (score 0):

OK. I'll bite.

Where is grabLatestWho() called from? 
Is that wrapped in your standard jquery load call?

```
$(document).ready(function() {grabLatestWho();}
```